# Identify if the string "geb." was entered

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I'd like to check if the string "geb." or "geb " was entered into a field. I am close to the solution, but the period is causing trouble for me:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" size="25"
    title="Hier nur Vor- und Nachnamen in dieser Reihenfolge eingeben (bitte ohne Zusatz des Geburtsnamens!)."
    value="Eva Gebhard geb. Zander" 
    onchange="if (Name.value.toUpperCase().search(' GEB[. ]') > -1) {alert('Die Angabe des Geburtsnamens ist nicht erforderlich. Bitte weglassen!'); setFocus(this); return false};" />
```

I've created a fiddle to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/spade/3rv2s3sc/
but couldn't figure it out.

Could someone, please, give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just `geb([. ])` analyze capture buffer 1 for dot or space.

Comment: Just a fyi, your regex has a space before GEB so that's what it's searching for as well. And doesn't JS need the regex to be in delimiters `/.../` ?

Comment: Don't use `search` with strings, pass a regex!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using the variable `Name` in your handler, which is undefined.  You need to test using `this`, which is the input element in the context of the handler.  Also, unless you have it defined elsewhere, setFocus() is not a function.  Use `this.focus()`, to reset the focus (though I'm assuming you're just doing that for testing reasons).

You don't need to use `/.../` to indicate a regex for Javscript's search function.  JS `search` will automatically convert a string into a regex.  However, Barmar's point of using `match` instead of `search` is a good one for your case, since you don't care about the index of where the match occurs in the string, only whether or not the string has an occurrence anywhere.

The note about your preceding space in your test is a good one too, since your questions asks about 'geb' and 'geb.'.  Assuming you phrased your question correctly, you shouldn't have the leading space in your condition test.

To show why your code didn't work, here is a working modification, keeping as much of it the same as possible, so you can understand your errors

```
<input type="text" name="Name" size="25" title="Hier nur Vor- und Nachnamen in dieser Reihenfolge eingeben (bitte ohne Zusatz des Geburtsnamens!)." value="Eva Gebhard geb. Zander" 
    onchange="if (this.value.toUpperCase().search(' GEB[. ]') > -1) {alert('Die Angabe des Geburtsnamens ist nicht erforderlich. Bitte weglassen!'); this.focus(); return false};" />
```

Here's another example showing some of the other user's comments incorporated:

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  value = el.value;
  if (value.match(/geb[. ]/i)) {
    alert('Die Angabe des Geburtsnamens ist nicht erforderlich. Bitte weglassen!'); 
    el.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="Name" size="25" title="Hier nur Vor- und Nachnamen in dieser Reihenfolge eingeben (bitte ohne Zusatz des Geburtsnamens!)." value="Eva Gebhard geb. Zander" onchange="myFunction(this)"/>
```

Comment: Tanks Bill, that is perfect as well!

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression has to be delimited with `/`, not `'`. Also, you shouldn't have a space at the beginning, unless you also require that. You can use `.match()` instead of `.search()` to just get a truthy/falsy value, instead of comparing with `-1`. And the `i` modifier makes the match case-insensitive, so you don't have to call `toUpperCase()`.

```js
$("input").change(function() {
  var Name = this;
  if (Name.value.match(/geb[. ]/i)) {
    alert('Die Angabe des Geburtsnamens ist nicht erforderlich. Bitte weglassen!');
    this.focus();
    return false
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks quite good, but it doesn't catch "Eva Gebhard geb Zander". I don't get it why.

Comment: It catches it for me.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for me. Its not supposed to trigger for Gebhard, but for the geb with or without period and with or without capital first letter. I created a fiddle, where I can't get it to trigger at all: https://jsfiddle.net/spade/jrr5jc9r/ Sorry for being such a pain ...

Comment: The variable `Name` isn't defined in your fiddle (names of inputs don't become global variables). Use `this.value` instead of `Name.value`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar for your kind effort. That's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This solution satisfies your requirements:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" size="25" 
 title="Hier nur Vor- und Nachnamen in dieser Reihenfolge eingeben (bitte ohne Zusatz des Geburtsnamens!)." 
 value="Eva Gebhard geb. Zander" 
 onchange="javascript:if(this.value.search(/\bgeb\.?\b/i) > -1){alert('Die Angabe des Geburtsnamens ist nicht erforderlich. Bitte weglassen!'); setFocus(this); return false};" 
/>
```

This is the regular expression in question:

```
/\bgeb\.?\b/i
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3rv2s3sc/6/

Explanation of regular expression:

- Fundamental knowledge:

  - Regular expressions in JavaScript are enclosed by forward slashes `/`
  - `\b` indicates a "word boundary." A word is not necessarily an actual word in a human language. It is defined as the beginning or end of "word characters." What those are depends on the context. In our case, we can think of it as a letter of the alphabet. For more info see [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
  - `.` is a special character meaning "any character." Therefore, if you want a plain period, you need to "escape the special character." The "escape character" is the backslash `\`. Therefore, the literal period is indicated `\.`
  - `?` is a special character that makes the preceding token optional. (A "token" is a character/group/subexpression.)
  - Following the closing forward slash of the regular expression you may specify a number of options or directives. The `i` here indicates "case insensitive." (That's why my solution does not require the `toUpperCase()` function.)
- Interpretation in ordinary language:

  - A regular expression matching `/`
  - a string beginning with a word boundary (could be following a space, a period, a dash, etc.—the point is, we are matching a distinct and separate word) `\b`,
  - the string `geb`,
  - an optional period character `\.?`,
  - and another word boundary `\b`,
  - the match being case insensitive. `/i`

For more information on JavaScript regular expressions, please see these websites:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html Comprehensive reference
- https://regex101.com/ Tool for trying and testing your own expressions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions Another helpful and authoritative reference

Comment: Thank you. This solution isn't catching "Eva Gebhard geb Zander" either. Am I missing something?

Comment: Apologies—I either misread the first line or had an earlier version of it. I updated my response to include the use of the special character `?` and a brief explanation of it.

Comment: Hi @FrankSpade! Does this now satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I tried to modify it to also trigger when geb is entered without the period, but that didn't work. It is not supposed to trigger for the name Gebhard or Gebba, Gebe, Gebbe, Gebine, Gebke, Gebkea or any such, just for " geb ", "Geb " or the same with a period. Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spade/c6c7cLem/

Comment: Hi @FrankSpade! I changed the solution to use word boundaries instead of space characters to target the geb./geb/Geb/Geb. pattern and avoid those other matches. Please see the updated explanation above, which includes a link to an updated JSFiddle. — Best, Zach

Comment: Thank you Zach, that did it! Thank you also for your expaination. You didn't just give me a fish, you tought me to fish myself. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, @FrankSpade! I'm so glad. Feel free to reach out to me any time. And, if you like this solution, please click to "accept" it. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<input type="text" name="Name" size="25" title="Hier nur Vor- und     Nachnamen in dieser Reihenfolge eingeben (bitte ohne Zusatz des Geburtsnamens!)." value="Eva Gebhard geb. Zander" 
            onchange="if (this.value.toUpperCase().match(/GEB/ ) )  {alert('Die Angabe des Geburtsnamens ist nicht erforderlich. Bitte   weglassen!'); setFocus(this); return false};" />
```

Comment: That will match `gebba`. He only wants to match `geb` if it's followed by `.` or space.